# android - MediaCodec decoder 1080p output yuv format

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Android MediaCodec can be used to decode output yuv420 format. I guess it should be NV12 format, but when I try it on Nexus6 7.1.1 device. The result is very stranger:

1. For 720p video, it works fine, the output yuv can be playbacked by ffplay with below command:

   ffplay -v info -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1280x720 out.yuv

   And the out.yuv file size is exactly width*height*3/2.
2. For 1080p video, the output yuv color not correct at top. And the out.yuv file size is 3133440, but width*height*3/2 should be 3110400, so another 23040 bytes is there.
   Sounds like the top layer color not correct.

[image]

When try to decode it to surface, it looks good. so I guess issue come from 1080p YUV package only.

Comment: Do not use yuv output, use Image output instead. refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#getOutputImage(int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1080p, it's very likely that the height of the actual decoded picture is 1920x1088, not 1920x1080. (1920x1088 adds up to the size of 3133440.) The bottommost 8 pixels are decoded and returned, but you're not supposed to show them.

In this case, the `MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT` field in the output `MediaFormat` probably is 1088, while the `crop-top` field is 0 and the `crop-bottom` is 1079. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java#976 for an example on how these fields are read.

As beetlej suggested, if you use the [`Image`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html) class received from the [`MediaCodec.getOutputImage`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#getOutputImage(int)) method (available since Android 5.0), these details will be taken care of.

Comment: @mstrosjo exactly, the output is 1920x1088 and crop-bottom is 1079. if I feed such yuv to encoder, should I add crop-bottom property also, if not, does that means encoder will do 1920x1088 to 1920x1080 convert?

Comment: It's not actually defined how to pass such data to the encoder - the official suggestion is to use `Surface` or `Image` for input which should take care of and handle all that. In practice, as far as I know, you don't need to do this padding for the height on encoding, on any device as far as I remember. A width that is not divisible by 16 is more problematic though; on some devices it works fine with any width, while others require you to pad the input data width to 16 pixels.